# get only that object from array of which which has the property true in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to the typescript. here, I have an array of an object which has few properties,

```
let data = [{
  "Id": "1",
  "Test": true
}, {

  "Id": "2",
  "Test": true
},
{

  "Id": "1",
  "Test": true,
  "ShowAttribute": true
}];

// Here, I am trying to get the data 

const getConfig = (ShowAttribute) => {
  return <Array<prod>>config?.appConfig?.attributes?.data ?? []
}

// this is the structure here I have added only the final object which is data.
```

Now, I am trying is

I am calling this method `getConfig` from two places where I am passing a variable that will give me the data on the basis of its value.

so, if the variable is false then it should return all the data which I am currently doing in the method getConfig, and if it is true then it should return the only object which has `ShowAttribute` property.

So, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so, if variable is false then it should return all the data which I am currently doing in the method getConfig, and if it is true then it should return the only object which has ShowAttribute property.

It sounds like you want to branch:

```
const getConfig = (ShowAttribute: boolean) => {
    if (ShowAttribute) {
        return data.filter(entry => "ShowAttribute" in entry);
        // Or if you mean the entry's `ShowAttribute` should be `true`:
        // return data.filter(({ShowAttribute}) => ShowAttribute);
    }
    return data; // Or maybe: `return data.slice()` if you want to make a defensive copy
};
```

...where `data` is the array you want to use (I couldn't tell what the real name of it is from your code; `config?.appConfig?.attributes?.data`?).

---

In a comment you've asked:

> just one thing How do I add that ?? for this if the data is not there as. an. empty array

Assuming your data is coming from `config?.appConfig?.attributes?.data`, you'd do something like this:

```
const getConfig = (ShowAttribute: boolean) => {
    const data = config?.appConfig?.attributes?.data ?? []; // <====
    if (ShowAttribute) {
        return data.filter(entry => "ShowAttribute" in entry);
        // Or if you mean the entry's `ShowAttribute` should be `true`:
        // return data.filter(({ShowAttribute}) => ShowAttribute);
    }
    return data; // Or maybe: `return data.slice()` if you want to make a defensive copy
};
```

Comment: just one thing How do I add that  ?? for this if the data is not there as. an. empty array

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how/where you'd do that.